Is either one of these proofs of $(A\cap B) \subseteq A\setminus(B\setminus A)$ objectively better than the other?
I feel Proof 2 is slightly more concise, and clicks with me more.
Claim:
$$(A\cap B) \subseteq A\setminus(B\setminus A)$$
Proof 1
Suppose $s \in (A\cap B)$
Since $s \in (A \cap B)$ this means $s \in A$ and $s \in B$.
If $s \in A$ and $s \in B$ then $s \notin (B\setminus A)$.
Therefore if $s \in A$ and $s \notin (B\setminus A)$ this means $s \in A\setminus(B\setminus A)$.
We have shown picking an arbitrary $s \in (A\cap B)$, that $s$ can be found in $A\setminus(B\setminus A)$.
Proof 2
Suppose $s \in (A\cap B)$
Since $(A \cap B) \subseteq A$ then $s \in A$.
Given $s \in A$ then $s \notin (B \setminus A)$.
With $s \in A$ and $s \notin (B \setminus A)$, we can conclude that $ s \in A\setminus(B\setminus A)$.
We have shown picking an arbitrary $s \in (A\cap B)$, that $s$ can be found in $A\setminus(B\setminus A)$.

Neither, a shorter proof would note that $A$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint, so $A \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$.

The first proof says "If $s \in A$ and $s \in B$ then $s \notin (B\setminus A)$" but you have already stablished that $s \in A$ and $s \in B$, so that line should be "Since $s \in A$ and $s \in B$ then $s \notin (B\setminus A)$"

Objectively? There is right and wrong, not "better" in evaluating proofs.

The most obvious thing is to just prove $A\setminus (B\setminus A)=A.$ And clearly $A\cap B\subseteq A.$ Indeed, you get a stronger result: $$A\cap C\subseteq A\setminus (B\setminus A)$$ for any three sets $A,B,C.$

Proof 2 is slightly better than Proof 1, insofar as one can compare two correct proofs. This is because you never mention the irrelevant fact that $s \in B$, which streamlines the argument.
In general, the concept of one proof being 'better' than another is highly subjective.
